# How to display the placeholder when CKEditor is activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, bootstrap-modal

How to display the placeholder attribute in HTML5 textarea when the CKEditor is activated or when click on edit

```
<textarea id="historyDescription" class="ckeditor" name="historyDescription" placeholder="historyDescription" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true"> </textarea>
```

when click on edit placeholder text should be display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Configuration Helper](http://ckeditor.com/addon/confighelper) plugin to get that behavior. Just add the plugin to your build and it should work automatically.

Comment: https://alfonsoml.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/placeholder-text-in-ckeditor.html

Comment: if u don't mind can u send with code for example.. i did't understand...

Comment: Do you know how to install CKEditor and create a build with an additional plugin or add one after initial install?

Comment: I don't know install CKEditor.. could u please Explain in Document....vinodreddy52@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```
var config = {};
config.placeholder = 'Place holder'; 
CKEDITOR.replace("editor1" , config );
```

Comment: i was used that scenario below text should apper                                                                                    Rich Text Editor, historyDescription Editor toolbars Basic Styles Bold ItalicParagraph Insert/Remove Numbered List Insert/Remove Bulleted List

Press ALT 0 for help

◢Elements path

Comment: Please, always give some explanation and not only the plain code

Comment: if u don't mind can u send with code for this example.. i did't understand